# R - Extract coefficients from a factor of lm object using conditions

Tags: r

I have fitted a lm with the following code:

```
Eq1_females = <- lm(earnings ~ event_time + factor(age) + factor(year) - 1, data=females)
```

Now, I would like to calculate a predicted value based on the factor coefficients, but this predicted value depends on certain conditions in the data. I therefore create a list of the coefficients and I now want to extract the factor coefficients if age = k and year = y, but it keeps returning 0 or NA. However, if I input a number (e.g. 34) instead of k, it does give the right value. I tried two different codes:

```
estimates <- coef(Eq1_females)
k = females$age[1]
Eq1_females$coefficients["factor(age)k"]
```

and

```
estimates <- coef(Eq1_females)
k = females$age[1]
beta_age = estimates[grep("^factor\\(age\\)k", names(estimates))]
```

(note that in the end, I would like to loop over different rows of females$age)

What does work, is calculating

```
beta_age = estimates[grep("^factor\\(age\\)34", names(estimates))]
```

Could anyone tell me if there is a way of also getting the code to work with k in the beta_age formula?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Could you maybe provide a small toy dataset, so that we can replicate it? Also, out of curiosity, why are you using `factor(age)` to begin with?

Comment: The dataset i'm using is not for public use, unfortunately. But I'm using factor(age) since I have to control for the age of individuals in the data (and also for the year in which a survey is conducted, hence the factor(year)). I thus basically have to find seperate coefficient estimates for each age

Comment: One simple alternative is to rewrite your problem in a dataset that is public, like `iris` (a default dataset in R, type `str(iris)` to see it). Also, if you want to control for age, then you are likely better off treating it as a continuous variable in the model. Using `factor` will create dummy variables for every level of `age`, which sounds suboptimal. Then again, you have probably thought about this yourself, but I just wanted to note it.

Comment: My regression specification requires me to treat each age level as a dummy, hence that is why I am using the factor for age.
With respect to the Iris dataset: I still don't get it to work there... Here is the code I am using (factoring for Petal.Width)
`Eq1 <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length + factor(Petal.Width) - 1, data=iris)
summary(Eq1)
estimates <- coef(Eq1)
k = iris$Petal.Width[1]
beta = estimates[grep("^factor\\(Petal.Width\\)k", names(estimates))]
`
But this also gives a beta of 0...

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**

Paste the right number to the regex pattern using `paste0`:

```r
beta = estimates[grep(paste0("^factor\\(Petal.Width\\)", k), names(estimates))]
```

This returns:

```
factor(Petal.Width)0.2 
              3.764947
```

**Rationale**

In `"^factor\\(age\\)k"`, it will treat `k` as the literal `k`. However, you are referring to variable `k`. By using `paste(..., sep = "")` or `paste0(...)` you can simply paste `k` to the base pattern.